# JS Лишняя прокрутка после анимации скролинга

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, animate

Есть у меня функция которая скроллит страницу к следующему элементу

```
animateScroll(direction) { // (-1,1)
    this.isAnimating = true;
    this.curIndex +=direction;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: this.coords[this.curIndex],
    }, this.speed, () => {
        this.isAnimating = false;
    });
}
```

Вызывается она по событию onscroll когда пользователь уходит за границы предыдущего элемента.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",(e) => {
        if (pageYOffset>this.coords[this.curIndex]+this.size && !this.isAnimating) {
            this.animateScroll(1);
        }
        if (pageYOffset<this.coords[this.curIndex]-this.size && !this.isAnimating) {
            this.animateScroll(-1);
        }
    });
```

Массив `this.coords` содержит координаты всех элементов, а конкретнее их отступ сверху от документа. `this.size` - размер отступа от текущего элемента при котором будет scroll к следующему

Так вот когда анимация заканчивается страница прокручивается еще немного вниз или вверх в зависимости от того насколько сильно свайпнул пользователь. В последствии данная функция вызывается еще раз т.к. из-за предыдущей лишней прокрутки пользователь опять уходит за границу уже текущего элемента.

Причем когда происходит обычный scroll колесиком мыши - все нормально.